# Last foreach loop in PowerShell fails but the previous loop works fine

Tags: powershell

This script is meant to help migrate from one domain to another. I'm looking for all of the AD security groups, then I pull the members of each group and create a text file with the name of the group and the members of that group.

I then want to create a new set of text files to include the information in the users `MailNickName` field for each group, this is called their `NID` (New ID). I use this `MailNickName` to store their `NID` for the new domain so I can push the `NID` to the proper groups in the new domain.

In the below script everything works except the last foreach loop, not sure why; it looks correct and I've searched the Internet for answers but no reason why this shouldn't work.

I don't get any error but the `$b` variable ends up being the same value as the `$iGroup` variable.  Also the new text file for the `NID` is never created.

```
$iScript = "GetADGroups"
$StrPath = "C:\Temp\$iScript"
$StrFile = "$StrPath\$iScript.txt"
if(!(Test-Path $StrPath)){New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $StrPath}

$OU1 = "OU=Users,OU=OC,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OU2 = "OU=Users,OU=AMC,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OU3 = "OU=Users,OU=FI,DC=domain,DC=com"

Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $OU1 | ft name -HideTableHeaders | Out-File "$strFile"
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $OU2 | ft name -HideTableHeaders | Out-File "$StrFile" -Append
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $OU3 | ft name -HideTableHeaders | Out-File "$StrFile" -Append

(GC $StrFile) | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""} | Set-Content $StrFile
$Groups = (GC $StrFile)
$Groups | foreach{$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content $StrFile
$Groups = (GC $StrFile)

foreach($Member in $Groups){
    foreach($a in $Member){
        if(Test-Path "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt"){Remove-Item -Path "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt" -Force}
        Write-Host $iMember
        $iMember = Get-ADGroupMember "$a" | Select-Object sAMAccountName
        $iMember | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-File "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt" -Append
        (GC "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt") | ? {$_.trim() -ne ""} | set-content "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt"
        (GC "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt") | foreach{$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt"
        GCI "$StrPath\$a.Members.txt" | where {$_.Length -lt 1} | Remove-Item
        }
    }

$GroupName = (GCI "$StrPath\*.Members.txt" -Name)
foreach($iGroup in $GroupName){
    foreach($b in $iGroup){
        if(Test-Path "$StrPath\$b.NID.txt"){Remove-Item -Path "$StrPath\$b.NID.txt" -Force}
        Write-Host $b
        Get-ADUser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq "$b"} -Properties MailNickName | Select-Object MailNickName | Set-Content "$StrPath\$b.NID.txt"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I would write out the source variables (or at least $iGroup) to the text file to visually inspect what you are starting with.  In my experience weirdness with text like this is usually due to some unexpected values.  If not can you provide what the input to this last set of loops is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `foreach($b in $iGroup)` loops a single item, they will always be equal. Demo:

   ```
   $GroupName = "Group1.Members.txt","Group2.Members.txt","Group3.Members.txt"
   foreach($iGroup in $GroupName){
       foreach($b in $iGroup){
           Write-Host $b
        }
   }
   Group1.Members.txt
   Group2.Members.txt
   Group3.Members.txt
   ```

   Sure you don't want to read the file? Ex.

   ```
   foreach($Group in (GCI "$StrPath\*.Members.txt")){
       Write-Host $Group.Name
       foreach($User in (Get-Content -Path $Group.FullName)){
           Write-Host $User
        }
   }
   ```
2. When exporting and importing objects, you rarely want to use `Format-*`-cmdlets as they are meant for displaying data in the console and breaks the objects. Because of this, you end up having to cleanup your text-file every time. I would highly recommend CSV-files using `Export-CSV` and `Import-CSV` or custom textfiles (if so, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` to only show groupname).
3. You are wasting time on reading, modifying and removing files. I would rewrite it to something like this:

   ```
   $iScript = "GetADGroups"
   $StrPath = "C:\Temp\$iScript"
   $StrFile = "$StrPath\$iScript.txt"
   #-Force to also create missing parents-folders
   if(!(Test-Path $StrPath)){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $StrPath -Force}

   $OUs = "OU=Users,OU=OC,DC=domain,DC=com", "OU=Users,OU=AMC,DC=domain,DC=com", "OU=Users,OU=FI,DC=domain,DC=com"
   $Groups = $OUs | Foreach-Object { Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $_ }
   #Save groupnames to file if you need them
   $Groups | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Set-Content -Path $StrFile

   foreach($group in $Groups){
       Write-Host $group
       $members = @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group)

       #If group contains members
       if($members.Count -gt 0) {
           #Create list of members
           $members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName | Set-Content -Path "$StrPath\$group.Members.txt"

           #Create list with new IDs (is the other list necessary?)
           $members | Get-ADUser -Properties MailNickName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MailNickName | Set-Content -Path "$StrPath\$group.NID.txt"
       }
   }
   ```

   And preferably merge the members and NID-list to a single csv-file where username and mailnickname are linked using a single row. Ex:

   ```
   #If group contains members
   if($members.Count -gt 0) {
       #Create csv-list of members with current username (samaccountname) and new id (mailnickname)
       $members | Get-ADUser -Properties MailNickName | Select-Object -Property sAMAccountName, MailNickName | Export-CSV -Path "$StrPath\$group.csv" -NoTypeInformation
   }
   ```

   Or take it one step further and simply have one csv-file with all group-memberships.

   ```
   $iScript = "GetADGroups"
   $StrPath = "C:\Temp\$iScript"
   $StrFile = "$StrPath\$iScript.txt"

   $OUs = "OU=Users,OU=OC,DC=domain,DC=com", "OU=Users,OU=AMC,DC=domain,DC=com", "OU=Users,OU=FI,DC=domain,DC=com"
   $Groups = $OUs | Foreach-Object { Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $_ }
   #Save groupnames to file if you need them (if you're migrating empty groups)
   $Groups | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Set-Content -Path $StrFile

   $Groups | Foreach-Object {
       $group = $_
       Write-Host $group
       Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
       #Getting ADUser object to get missing property
       Get-ADUser -Properties MailNickName |
       Select-Object -Property @{n="Group";e={$group}}, sAMAccountName, MailNickName
   } | Export-CSV -Path "$StrPath\GroupMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
   ```

   Your CSV would look like this, which can easily be imported, grouped etc. later with `Import-CSV` when adding members to the new groups:

   ```
   Group,sAMAccountName,MailNickName
   Group1,user1,mailnickforuser1
   Group2,user1,mailnickforuser1
   Group2,user2,mailnickforuser2
   ```

Comment: Wow you made it so much easier.  I like the last CSV file, but I had to add a "-append" to the Export-CSV line otherwise I ended up with just one entry group.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to change the foreach-loop to a pipeline-foreach. Updated csv-solution now. :-)

Comment: I think I have some groups with some errors in them so I added the 
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
to the Get-ADGroupMember and Get-ADUser lines.

Comment: Frode, I found out why I was getting the errors, some of the security groups contain computers not just users so when it checked for the MailNickName using Get-ADUser it spits out an error message.

Comment: Frode, I'm trying to filter the list of GET-ADUSERS so I don't get disabled users.  I don't need them and their MailNickName field will be blank.  When I try to add "-Filter (Enabled -eq 'True')" I get incorrect results.  I also tried to add it to the GET_ADGROUP filter but that's not the appropriate location for users.

Comment: `"Enabled -eq $true"`. I would add this as a where-statement since I don't believe you can mix Identity (pipe in objects) and filter. Add ` Where-Object { $_.Enabled } |` after `Get-ADUser .... |`

Comment: Worked great thanks.  I also added " | Sort-Object -Property DistinguishedName" to the end of $Groups = $OUs line to sort my list.

Comment: any way to get the group name instead of the DistinguishedName?  I've tried various options but none come out with just the name.

Comment: Where? My solution never used distinguishedname, it used Group name

Comment: It was in the way the group was pulled.  Ignore, I knew as soon as I asked I would find it.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Didn't notice that expand name was only done for the text file. Use `@{n="Group";e={$group.Name}}` in the select at the end (before export to csv)